# I used while loop and my project become not responding (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, function, while-loop

I'm beginner in MATLAB programming.
I'm working on statistic data and I have some problem with while looping. Here's the codes :

```
% --- Executes on button press in b_analisa_data.
function b_analisa_data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
hitung(handles.lb_tkp, handles);
tkp=getappdata(handles.lb_tkp,'tkp2');
tpp=getappdata(handles.lb_tpp,'tpp2');
po=getappdata(handles.lb_po,'po2');
nq=getappdata(handles.lb_nq,'nq2');
nt=getappdata(handles.lb_nt,'nt2');
tq=getappdata(handles.lb_tq,'tq2');
tt=getappdata(handles.lb_tt,'tt2');
s=getappdata(handles.lb_s,'s2');

set(handles.lb_tkp,'String',tkp);
set(handles.lb_tpp,'String',tpp);
set(handles.lb_po,'String',po);
set(handles.lb_nq,'String',nq);
set(handles.lb_nt,'String',nt);
set(handles.lb_tq,'String',tq);
set(handles.lb_tt,'String',tt);
set(handles.lb_s,'String',s);
% hObject    handle to b_analisa_data (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


function hitung(handles_hitung,handles)
% Perhitungan tingkat kedatangan pelanggan (TKP)
a=str2num(get(handles.st_twak,'String'));
b=str2num(get(handles.st_jwak,'String'));
param=str2num(get(handles.txt_param,'String'));
c=a/b;
t=3600;
tkp=t/c;
%set(handles.lb_tkp,'String',tkp);

% Perhitungan tingkat pelayanan pelanggan (TPP)
d=str2num(get(handles.st_twp,'String'));
e=str2num(get(handles.st_jwp,'String'));
f=d/e;
tpp=t/f;
%set(handles.lb_tpp,'String',tpp);

% Perhitungan probabilitas tidak adanya pelanggan (PO)
s=str2num(get(handles.st_kasir,'String'));
g=tkp/tpp;
h=tkp/(s*tpp);
for i=0:s-1;
    j(i+1)=(g^i)/(factorial(i));
end
k=sum(j);
l=g/((factorial(s)*(1-h)));
m=k+l;
po=1/m;
%set(handles.lb_po,'String',po);

% Perhitungan jumlah pelanggan dalam antrian (NQ)
n=po*(g^s)*h;
o=factorial(s);
p=o*((1-h)^2);
nq=n/p;
%set(handles.lb_nq,'String',nq);

% Perhitungan jumlah pelanggan dalam sistem (NT)
nt=nq+g;
%set(handles.lb_nt,'String',nt);

% Perhitungan waktu tunggu rata-rata dalam antrian (TQ)
tq=nq/tkp;
%set(handles.lb_tq,'String',tq);

% Perhitungan waktu tunggu rata-rata dalam sistem (TT)
q=tq+(1/tpp);
tt= q*60;
%set(handles.lb_tt,'String',tt);

% Perhitungan jumlah kasir (S)
%set(handles.lb_s,'String',s);

while tt>param
    s=s-1;
    tkp=t/c;
    tpp=t/f;
    po=1/m;
    nq=n/p;
    nt=nq+g;
    tq=nq/tkp;
    tt= q*60;
end
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tkp2',tkp);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tpp2',tpp);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'po2',po);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'nq2',nq);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'nt2',nt);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tq2',tq);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tt2',tt);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'s2',s);
```

My project will calculate statistic data using more than one formula. So, I put on all the formula within "function hitung"

```
function hitung(handles_hitung,handles)
% Perhitungan tingkat kedatangan pelanggan (TKP)
a=str2num(get(handles.st_twak,'String'));
b=str2num(get(handles.st_jwak,'String'));
param=str2num(get(handles.txt_param,'String'));
c=a/b;
t=3600;
tkp=t/c;
%set(handles.lb_tkp,'String',tkp);

% Perhitungan tingkat pelayanan pelanggan (TPP)
d=str2num(get(handles.st_twp,'String'));
e=str2num(get(handles.st_jwp,'String'));
f=d/e;
tpp=t/f;
%set(handles.lb_tpp,'String',tpp);

% Perhitungan probabilitas tidak adanya pelanggan (PO)
s=str2num(get(handles.st_kasir,'String'));
g=tkp/tpp;
h=tkp/(s*tpp);
for i=0:s-1;
    j(i+1)=(g^i)/(factorial(i));
end
k=sum(j);
l=g/((factorial(s)*(1-h)));
m=k+l;
po=1/m;
%set(handles.lb_po,'String',po);

% Perhitungan jumlah pelanggan dalam antrian (NQ)
n=po*(g^s)*h;
o=factorial(s);
p=o*((1-h)^2);
nq=n/p;
%set(handles.lb_nq,'String',nq);

% Perhitungan jumlah pelanggan dalam sistem (NT)
nt=nq+g;
%set(handles.lb_nt,'String',nt);

% Perhitungan waktu tunggu rata-rata dalam antrian (TQ)
tq=nq/tkp;
%set(handles.lb_tq,'String',tq);

% Perhitungan waktu tunggu rata-rata dalam sistem (TT)
q=tq+(1/tpp);
tt= q*60;
%set(handles.lb_tt,'String',tt);

% Perhitungan jumlah kasir (S)
%set(handles.lb_s,'String',s);

while tt>param
    s=s-1;
    tkp=t/c;
    tpp=t/f;
    po=1/m;
    nq=n/p;
    nt=nq+g;
    tq=nq/tkp;
    tt= q*60;
end
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tkp2',tkp);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tpp2',tpp);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'po2',po);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'nq2',nq);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'nt2',nt);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tq2',tq);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'tt2',tt);
setappdata(handles_hitung,'s2',s);
```

And I call "function hitung" within "function b_analisa_data Callback"

```
function b_analisa_data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    hitung(handles.lb_tkp, handles);
    tkp=getappdata(handles.lb_tkp,'tkp2');
    tpp=getappdata(handles.lb_tpp,'tpp2');
    po=getappdata(handles.lb_po,'po2');
    nq=getappdata(handles.lb_nq,'nq2');
    nt=getappdata(handles.lb_nt,'nt2');
    tq=getappdata(handles.lb_tq,'tq2');
    tt=getappdata(handles.lb_tt,'tt2');
    s=getappdata(handles.lb_s,'s2');

    set(handles.lb_tkp,'String',tkp);
    set(handles.lb_tpp,'String',tpp);
    set(handles.lb_po,'String',po);
    set(handles.lb_nq,'String',nq);
    set(handles.lb_nt,'String',nt);
    set(handles.lb_tq,'String',tq);
    set(handles.lb_tt,'String',tt);
    set(handles.lb_s,'String',s);
    % hObject    handle to b_analisa_data (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

My program will dislpay all the result from calculating the formulas in 8 listboxes. But I had no idea to call the "function hitung" so it can be displayed in 8 listboxes as well. I tried the codes bellow and got some errors :

```
function b_analisa_data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        hitung(handles.lb_tkp,handles.lb_tpp, handles);
        ....
```

So, I tried with only 1 listbox and it works as long as program didn't use the while loop.

```
function b_analisa_data_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        hitung(handles.lb_tkp, handles);
        ...
```

If the condition make the program use while loop, then it become not responding. I still confused why it turns out like this.

Comment: Where's the while loop you're putting in? It's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 3):

I see you have this while loop:

```
while tt>param
    s=s-1;
    tkp=t/c;
    tpp=t/f;
    po=1/m;
    nq=n/p;
    nt=nq+g;
    tq=nq/tkp;
    tt= q*60;
end
```

Both `tt` and `param` will never be changed (well `tt` can change the first time). So once you are in the second iteration, you can never get out.

---

Some guesses of what you may want, if it is not just a typo:

1. If you only want to do this once, replace the `while` with an `if`
2. If you want to wait till a variable get updated, you need to put everything that is required for updating this variable inside the loop. (for example `getappdata`)

Answer (score 0):

Dennis is right.  Another guess at what you may want is to make sure `q` gets updated.  As you have it, `q` is set outside the while loop and never changes inside.

Since you have

```
tt= q*60;
```

`q` needs to be updated inside the loop in order for `tt` to be as well.